# Apply Styles to DataGridTextColumn with MahApps Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I just tried using the following XAML in my WPF application.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Due" Binding="{Binding QTYDue, Mode=OneWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Unfortunately, the behavior is that the previous styling for the control in MahApps Metro is removed. How do I keep the existing style, but just modify this one aspect of it.

[image: WPF Behavior]

Comment: Have you tried <Style BasedOn="..." > ?

Comment: Yeah, but after that I'm not sure how to get the Style defined in DataGridTextColumn to match.  Tried a bunch of different ways of referencing the Styles in the Resource for MahApps.Metro.Controls, but havent figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

**Style:**

```
<Style x:Key="DatagridCellStyle1" 
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

**XAML:**

```
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DUE" 
                            Binding="{Binding QTYDue}" 
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource DatagridCellStyle1}" />
```

OR

```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="DUE">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGridCell Style="{StaticResource DatagridCellStyle1}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding QTYDue}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataGridCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

[image]